# Expected ';' at end of declaration

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Am getting this error message for the following code, but it doesn't make sense at all. Can you please check this code and tell what's wrong? Have commented the code on the relevant line.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct {
    float exchangeRate;
    double budget;
    double euroTransaction;
} budget;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    budget vacationBudget;

    void spendDollars (double dollars) {  //Expected ';' at end of declaration
        vacationBudget.budget -= 100;
    }

    void chargeEuros(double euros) {
        vacationBudget.euroTransaction = euros*vacationBudget.exchangeRate;
        vacationBudget.budget -= vacationBudget.euroTransaction;
    }

    vacationBudget.exchangeRate = 1.2500;
    vacationBudget.budget = 1000.00;
    double numberDollars = 100;
    double numberEuros = 100;

    spendDollars(numberDollars);
    NSLog(@"Converting %.2f US dollars into euros leaves $%.2f", numberDollars, vacationBudget.budget);



    NSLog(@"Charging %.2f euros leaves $%.2f", numberEuros, vacationBudget.budget);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see this objective C.  I believe there's a way to tell to the GCC compiler, for example, to allow for functions to be declared within functions, even though this behavior isn't allowed by default.  There may be a way to do this if you absolutely don't want the functions outside main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funcitions can't be inside main. Change to:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    typedef struct {
        float exchangeRate;
        double budget;
        double euroTransaction;
    } budget;

budget vacationBudget;

void spendDollars (double dollars) {  //Expected ';' at end of declaration
            vacationBudget.budget -= 100;
    }

    void chargeEuros(double euros) {
            vacationBudget.euroTransaction = euros*vacationBudget.exchangeRate;
            vacationBudget.budget -= vacationBudget.euroTransaction;
    }

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        vacationBudget.exchangeRate = 1.2500;
        vacationBudget.budget = 1000.00;
        double numberDollars = 100;
        double numberEuros = 100;

        spendDollars(numberDollars);
        NSLog(@"Converting %.2f US dollars into euros leaves $%.2f", numberDollars, vacationBudget.budget);



        NSLog(@"Charging %.2f euros leaves $%.2f", numberEuros, vacationBudget.budget);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This will fail as the functions are not declared prior to main.

Comment: @PeterM Even worse: this code uses undeclared names in both moved functions, it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @sidyll He would have get a warning because the functions were after the method, but it would not fail because of that. The variable would give a complie error though.

Answer (score 3):

Move the spendDollars and chargeEuros functions outside of the main function.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great idea to have a function within a function (as in it won't compile - i.e. what you're seeing - and it doesn't make logical sense), move spendDollars and changeEuros outside of main and pass vacationBudget as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

That's because  you're *defining*  a function (`spendDollars`)  inside another
function (`main`). Nested  functions are not allowed,  they're always "global"
in that sense.

However, you're  allowed to  *declare* a function  inside another,  which then
acts as a clue to the compiler: that function is declared elsewhere but now it
knows the parameters  and return type (which  defaults to `int` if  you use an
un-declared function).

So, then  the compiler sees  the function  syntax inside another  function, it
expects it to  be a *declaration*, just like function  signatures. And then it
sees  the opening  brace  and generates  an error,  as  the declaration  ended
without a semicolon before the following block.

You need  to move  the functions `spendDollars`  and `chargeEuros`  to outside
`main`, and for that reason you have to pass a reference to the local variable
you want to modify. These should work:

```
void spendDollars (budget *b, double dollars)
{
    b->budget -= 100;
}

void chargeEuros(budget *b, double euros) {
    b->euroTransaction = euros*vacationBudget.exchangeRate;
    b->budget -= vacationBudget.euroTransaction;
}
```

Note that the  `->` operator will work  directly on the pointer,  just like if
you had used

```
(*b).budget -= 100;
```

To dereference the  pointer and operate on the struct.  Call your new function
as

```
spendDollars(&vacationBudget, numberDollars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `spendDollars` and `chargeEuros` can't be in the main.

But its not true that you can't create methods in methods. Sinds iOS 4.0 you can create Blocks.

For more information follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9438/how-to-use-blocks-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2) tutorial about Blocks